# Trigger when viewing a certain sheet in google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

Is there a trigger in Google apps script when a certain sheet comes to view? Please give some sample code. Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use trigger when someone is editing and getActiveSheet method.
Something like:

```
let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
let sheet = 'stack questions';
let activeSheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    if (activeSheet === sheet) {
    console.log(`The sheet ${sheet} is in use`):
    }
    else { console.log(`The sheet ${activeSheet} is the one in use`)}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no trigger to determine which sheet is currently being viewed.
And even if you try to use a combination of a time trigger and getActiveSheet() or getCurrentCell(), you will get Sheet1.
But by using onEdit(), you can determine which sheet is currently being edited.

```
function onEdit() {
  var activeSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  Logger.log(activeSheet.getName());
  if (activeSheet.getName() === "Sheet2") {
    Logger.log("Gotcha!");
  }
}
```

Comment: @Stack I'm not sure I understood you correctly. To determine which sheet is being edited, my code does not use an event object, but getActiveSheet(). onEdit() is needed here to determine whether the sheet has been edited and run the function.

Comment: Please read the documentation on [simple triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers?hl=ru#onedite). It is not explicitly stated there, but it is known from experience that a simple trigger fires if it is onEdit(), but not, for example, onEdit2().

Comment: You should better understand the difference between a simple and a installable trigger. "Simple triggers are a set of reserved functions built into Apps Script." Why do we love triggers so much? Because they give us information about: A) the fact of the event, B) the details of the event. In this case, point B is unimportant, since the sheet name is not getted from "e". But point A is important here, since in this case the simple trigger onEdit() is a reserved function and requires exactly this writing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257299/discussion-between-boris-baublys-and-stack).

Comment: "the code you answered is NOT a trigger because it does not have an event object (e)"
The word "trigger" means some element that sets something into action. This is the main function of a trigger - to start something. Even if it does not transmit information about the event that pulled the trigger.